# Explain chkdsk switches in more detail

Tags: error-handling

/f /r
What is the difference between fixing and recovering bad sectors?

/c 
Eli5 "Skips the checking of cycles within the folder structure." Can someone explain this.

/i
Eli5 "Performs a simpler check of index entrie."

Also any info online that will explain the rest in detail would be most helpful.

Comment: Add some system tags, like windows, or recovery

Answer (score 0):

`/r` tries to recover any readable part of the sector

to be totally honest, there is nothing like recovering the sector itself, if it failed once, it is almost certain to fail again so the utility marks it as unusable, in both `/f` and `/r`, but the later at least tries to read some thing first.

`/c` cycles happens when the folder A 'contains' folder B, that 'contains' A, of corse no one contains anything at that level, they are all lists of references, so this cycling could happens. Using this option reduce the time to check, but skip checking for this very specific kind of error, if you are not worring about it.

`/i` Well, every folder (and the partition itself) is a special file with lot of references, instead of checking if the referenced file id really there, and if it is readable, one could simply check if the index have any error in it's structure, and forget about the actual data.

Please look at [the manual](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714(v=ws.11).aspx#code-snippet-1) first